# How to use a custom method to call inner object method in object will typed in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, frontend, typescript-typings

I want to access my method property in object by called `this.getMethod` just like below:

```js
function defineObj(params) {
    // `enhanced` will add `getMethod` to params.__prop__
    return enhanced(params)
}

let obj = defineObj({
    methods: {
        foo: (num) => num,
        bar() {
            this.getMethod('foo', 1) // will call as `this.methods.foo(1)`
        }
    }
})
```

Now, I am plan to move those codes to Typescript and get type hinting.

when I call `this.getMethod('foo', '1')`, I want IDE tell me, I should use `number` instead of `string`. And I just want to knew how to use Typescript's Type to complete it.

I wrote codes to do that, but failed.

I am trying to define this context of methods by use `CtrlContext`. So I can use `this.getMethod` in function body of `methods.foo`.

```js
type CtrlContext<M> = {
    getMethod: <T extends keyof M>(name: T, ...params:  M[T] extends (...arg: infer S2) => infer S1 ? S2 : any[] ) => any
}

type Methods<M> = {
    [K in keyof M]: (this: CtrlContext<M>, ...params: any) => ReturnType<any>
}

type Ctrls<M> = {
    methods: Methods<M>
}

function defineObj<M>(params: Ctrls<M>) {
    return params
}

defineObj({
    methods: {
        foo: (num: number) => num,
        foo2: (num1: number, str: string) => num,
        bar() {
            this.getMethod("foo", ) // Now, the second param is any, not number.
        }
    }
})

export default {}
```

[image]

[codes online](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?isolatedModules=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAwsBOAbGB7AdsCAPYAeAsgHxQC8UA3gFBQ1QDmEw+jAFigCYBcUuAKlNkxp2AZygBrCCBQAzKEQAUaAIYBbCN14AaKADp9YZfDUju8gNq8AugJwRhYhft1G63AJZoZEeFADKAEwAlKTEnt6+fgCMUAD8-gFQ3MpoIOY2ISTEKSCUAL6UlKCQ8qwcIgTEZFS0UOYA0lCeElKy8lbcCsAs7qawCMjomDiVOs6Gxqp9OZnEAEqMAK7waLzgELg5hPmFxdBwSBVEpBTUtOrd5dzMl6KVO5Qyi2gAxsDu6FDsEDKeEADyACMAFaVBQTEzcA6II6EEI1WjwJYrKAQqYPb6-NAAkEKBE0C5sUTcfG1KAyFAoTpoRaqbg01SAnyzKAMrRnMlQQFGBTwjmc2jdXq6BhMMrsBQAIgpKElOiC-NqBSV+QVlGwYBQ8GAXx+ykWiB15AKQA)

Now, I can get type hinting of first parameter, but can't get function parameter hinting after I input first parameter. Is there some way to solve it ?

Comment: Your `defineObj` does nothing apart from return the params you sent.  Typescript does not add functions for you.  IOW: `getMethod` does not exist anywhere in your code.

Comment: If the purpose `defineObj` is only for the generic type, then you might be overthinking things: you can directly use other methods in `this`, without having to create a "getMethod" helper, and directly have type safety: https://tsplay.dev/NBR6zN

Comment: My purpose is not call `foo` in `bar`, I knew I can directly use it. But in my project, I must use `getMethod` to call a method.

Answer (score 0):

I did not see definition of `getMethod()` method in your code. For type parameters. You can simply define them in the method declaration itself.

```
getMethod(name: string, value: number) {
}
```

and then, If you will assign second param as a string while calling. Typescript will give the error.

```
this.getMethod('foo', '1') ❌

this.getMethod('foo', 1) ✅
```

Comment: I defined `getMethod` in this context by `CtrlContext`. the `getMethod` is in the prototype and I omitted it . I don't want to change it. Is there some way to only declare `getMethod` in `CtrlContext` to achieve it ?

Comment: @mysteryven  `CtrlContext` is a type, that's it, nothing more nothing less.  Like I mentioned in the comments no code for `getMethod` has been generated, all you have created is a Type that has a getMethod, that somewhere needs implementing..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of TypeScript's capabilities to do what you want. Someone else might have a better idea.

However, you could always wrap these methods such that it appears as a regular TypeScript function, that way it looks nicer to the outside and can also incorporate type safety.

```
class Wrapper {
  constructor(getMethod) {
    this.getMethod = getMethod;
  }

  foo(n: number) {
    this.getMethod("foo", n);
  }

  // include all other methods here
}
```

This is obviously a very tedious task and might not be suitable for your use-case, but I thought it was worth mentioning anyway.

You might be able to create a code generation tool for this as well.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by use [`ThisType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#thistypetype) and [this example](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/blob/main/questions/00006-hard-simple-vue/README.md).

```js
type AnyFunction = (...args: any) => any

type CtrlContext<M> = {
    getMethod: 
    <T extends keyof M>(name: T, ...params: Parameters<T extends keyof M ? M[T] extends AnyFunction ? M[T] : never : never>) => 
        ReturnType<T extends keyof M ? M[T] extends AnyFunction ? M[T] : never : never>
}

type Methods<M> = {
    [T in keyof M]: M[T]
}

type Ctrls<M> = {
    methods: Methods<M> & ThisType<CtrlContext<M>>
}

function defineObj<M>(params: Ctrls<M>) {
    return params
}

defineObj({
    methods: {
        foo(num: number) {
            return num
        },
        bar() {
            const val = this.getMethod("foo", 1)
                        // ^^^ (property) getMethod: <"foo">(name: "foo", num: number) => number

        }
    }
})
```

[online](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?isolatedModules=true#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)